# Atlas from human brain structures to 3D coordinates?

Tags: human-anatomy, brain

I would like to visualize specific human brain structures in the three dimensional space and compute specific geometric properties of these brain structures (size, centroid, etc).

Therefore, I am looking for an atlas that maps human brain structures to 3D coordinates (in Talairach or MNI coordinates).

I saw online a lot of websites allowing the inverse mapping, which is from coordinates to brain structures. So I know that this data should be somewhere but I was not able to find it.

Any lead would be greatly appreciated.